# Swift Core Bluetooth - discoverServices - What happens if no service can be found?

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I'm working with Core Bluetooth in Swift and I'm wondering what happens after I called `discoverServices([myServiceUUIDs])` in case that no services that are matching can be found.
The `connect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, options: [String: Any]? = nil)` has `didConnect` and `didFailToConnect`. So I have a case that gets called if it fails.
But on `discoverServices()` the documentation says only

> When the peripheral discovers one or more services, it calls the peripheral(_:didDiscoverServices:) method of its delegate object.

So in the "happy case" that it finds the services I can continue doing stuff. But how do I know that it can't find any services? Is there also a method for or do I have to use a Timer and just cancel after a defined time and assume that there is not the service I was looking for?

Answer (score 1):

It keeps looking until you turn it off. You have to use a timer or give the user a button to stop searching (or both.)

### Additional

After reading some of the comments, an analogy might be in order... Imagine if someone told you to "find all the blue eggs". When would you stop?

If you answer, "I would stop when I found all the blue eggs," how do you *know* you found them all? How do you know someone won't hide more blue eggs while you are looking?

You can't know, so you keep looking until your told to stop.

Why would you "error"? You would only error if you can't look for eggs for some reason, maybe you got stuck while looking under the couch...

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for your answer.
I'm confused about that because the `peripheral(_:didDiscoverServices:)` has also an `error` parameter. What is it for? And why is it possible that it tries to discover services "for ever"? I mean, before we call the `discoverServices` method, we connected us to the peripheral. So actually it should be possible to know if the peripheral has a service with the given UUID or not. The Services are fix things that don't just randomly show up and go. IF they wouldn't be fix, it makes sense to continuously "scan" for a service.

Comment: There is a difference between discovering peripherals that are advertising a service and discovering a connected peripheral's services. The first is a passive operation.  Ios  listens for peripheral advertisements that have the service you specify. It keeps listening for a matching advertisement until you tell it to stop. At any instant there may be 0 or more peripherals in range and advertising the service.  The second operation is an active communication between the iOS device and a specific, connected peripheral. That can fail and return an error.

Comment: @Paulw11 so for discovering services, I don't need a timeout. The called delegate has an error parameter and if this one is not nil, something went wrong or no service is found. Is that correct?
Is that the same for read and wirte operations? The called delegate will show me if it was successful by the error parameter?

Comment: If no service is found (which I think is probably not a possible situation) then you would get an empty services array and no error. For read, you will get an error if something goes wrong. For write you will get an error if you use write with response and something goes wrong.